# If $a=b+ c$ and $E$ is the basis of $a$, Will $E$ be also basis for $b$ and $c$?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Suppose $a$ lies in the span of a set of independent vectors $E$. Now, if $a=b+c$, is it also the case that $b$ and $c$ lie in the span o the same set of vectors $E$?

if the question is obscure, please let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear. "$E$ is the basis for $a$" only makes sense if $a$ is a vector space, and even then it should be "$E$ is a basis for $a$". But from the other things you write, it seems that $a,b,c$ are vectors, not vector spaces. You have to figure out what you actually mean here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For example, try $b = e_1 - e_2$ and $c = e_1 + e_2$ where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are independent vectors.  Then $a = 2 e_1$ is a linear combination of $e_1$, but $b$ and $c$ are not.

Comment: thanks sir. Really its very simple.